# Changing background color of td based on php array value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

With below code I am trying to change background color of td element. I think code needs correction, any help please. It's not applying color. or any other better solution.

**PHP code:**

```
$color = "#000000";
if (($change[array_keys($change)[0]] < 0))
$color = "#E54028";
    else if (($change[array_keys($change)[0]] >= 1) && ($change[array_keys($change)[0]] <= 19))
       $color = "#F18D05";
    else if ($change[array_keys($change)[0]] >= 20)
       $color = "#61AE24";
```

**Td element:**

```
<td <?php echo "style=background: $color";?>><?php echo $change[array_keys($change)[0]];?>%</td>
```

[image: Table after WangJie code]

Comment: try <td bgcolor="<?php echo $color; ?>" >

Comment: Nothing changed, tried: ` <td bgcolor="<?php echo $color; ?>"><?php echo $change[array_keys($change)[0]];?>%</td>`. echo value in td is -50%.

Comment: can you post the output of var_dump($change);

Comment: It returns lengthy calculation, `$change[array_keys($change)[0]]` returns `float -50`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hm, did you tried this? 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp

```
<?php echo "style='background-color:{$color};' "; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are your `td` tags in the `table`? The `td` tag must be the table cell and  attribute of html tag must be quoted by `"` or `'`. following code is work fine on me.

```
<?php
$change['a'] = 10;
$color = "#000000";
if ($change[array_keys($change)[0]] < 0)
$color = "#E54028";
else if (($change[array_keys($change)[0]] >= 1) && ($change[array_keys($change)[0]] <= 19))
$color = "#F18D05";
else if ($change[array_keys($change)[0]] >= 20)
$color = "#61AE24";
?>

<table>
 <td <?php echo "style=\"background: $color\"";?>><?php echo $change[array_keys($change)[0]];?>%</td>
</table>
```

---

When you face repetitive elements you should use `foreach` loop. It is easy in this situation, you just add `foreach` outside those code like this:

```
<?php
foreach ($change as $item) {
  $color = "#000000";
  if ($item < 0)
  $color = "#E54028";
  else if (($item >= 1) && ($item <= 19))
  $color = "#F18D05";
  else if ($item >= 20)
  $color = "#61AE24";?>
  <td <?php echo "style=\"background: $color\"";?>><?php echo $item;?>%</td>
<?php } ?>
```

---

Normally a table is composed of two-dimensional array so loop twice can do it, but if the situation in your form is more complicated you can not do that. You can create a function and call them when needed if you just want to simply achieve your need. Because I do not know your specific needs so I can only give you this simple suggestion.

Comment: Yes, `td` is inside table tag. With above marked answer it's working now. I may have to repeat php code 8 times as I have 2 arrays each having 4 `td` elements. Will there be any other better solution? Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: @SamadhanGaikwad Just use `foreach` and I have update the answer to show you how to use it.

Comment: nice solution but that gives output in row, I want them in column. See image uploaded.